# The purpose of introducing nn.Parameter in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch and I am confused about the difference between `nn.Parameter`  and `autograd.Variable`. I know that the former one is the subclass of `Variable` and has the gradient. But I really don't understand why we introduce `Parameter` and when we should use it?

---

**SUMMARY**:

Thanks for the explanation of iacolippo, i finally understand the difference between `parameter` and `variable`. In a summary, `variable` in pytorch is NOT same as in  the `variable` in tensorflow, the former one is not attach to the model's trainable parameters while the later one will. Attaching to the model means that using `model.parameters()` will return the certain parameter to you, which is useful in training phase to specify the variable needed to train. The 'variable' is more helpful as a cache in some network.

Comment: switch to 0.4 version, and you won't have variables.

Comment: @Paddy Hi paddy, i still have Variable after i switched to version 0.4.0

Comment: you don't need to use Variable. Sorry for the later answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

`Parameters` are `Tensor` subclasses, that have a very special property when used with `Module`s - when they’re assigned as `Module` attributes they are automatically added to the list of its parameters, and will appear e.g. in `parameters()` iterator. Assigning a Tensor doesn’t have such effect. This is because one might want to cache some temporary state, like last hidden state of the `RNN`, in the model. If there was no such class as `Parameter`, these temporaries would get registered too.

Think for example when you initialize an optimizer:

`optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)`

The optimizer will update only registered `Parameters` of the model.

`Variable`s are still present in Pytorch 0.4 but they are deprecated. From the docs:

The `Variable` API has been deprecated: `Variable`s are no longer necessary to use `autograd` with tensors. Autograd automatically supports `Tensors` with `requires_grad` set to `True`.

---

### Pytorch pre-0.4

In Pytorch before version 0.4 one needed to wrap a `Tensor` in a `torch.autograd.Variable` in order to keep track of the operations applied to it and perform differentiation. From the docs of `Variable` in 0.3:

Wraps a tensor and records the operations applied to it.
`Variable` is a thin wrapper around a `Tensor` object, that also holds the gradient w.r.t. to it, and a reference to a function that created it. This reference allows retracing the whole chain of operations that created the data. If the `Variable` has been created by the user, its `grad_fn` will be `None` and we call such objects leaf `Variables`.
Since `autograd` only supports scalar valued function differentiation, `grad` size always matches the `data` size. Also, `grad` is normally only allocated for leaf variables, and will be always zero otherwise.

The difference wrt `Parameter` was more or less the same. From the docs of `Parameters` in 0.3:

A kind of `Variable` that is to be considered a module parameter.
`Parameters` are `Variable` subclasses, that have a very special property when used with `Module`s - when they’re assigned as `Module` attributes they are automatically added to the list of its parameters, and will appear e.g. in `parameters()` iterator. Assigning a `Variable` doesn’t have such effect. This is because one might want to cache some temporary state, like last hidden state of the RNN, in the model. If there was no such class as `Parameter`, these temporaries would get registered too.

Another difference is that parameters can’t be volatile and that they require gradient by default.

Comment: Thanks, now i know that the parameter in pytorch acts like variable in tensorflow. And, just for curiosity, why pytorch before version 0.4.0 introduced the parameter? is there any difference between parameter and variable before version 0.4.0?

Comment: i got it. It seems that 'variable' is useful, then why it will be deprecated?

Comment: It is deprecated because Tensor now has that behavior, without the need to wrap it in another class